# Change Facebook login background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-facebook

I have the following code used as a facebook login. I followed their tutorial and implemented Facebook login into my android app. Now I want to change the login button background. How can I do that?

XML file:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/google_button" />
```

in MainActivity:

```
    facebook_login_button.setReadPermissions("email", "public_profile")
    facebook_login_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
```

Comment: If you want to use your own widget for it's login, it's best you look into implementing everything needed for logging in by using it's `FacebookSdk` and `CallbackManager`as well as registering callbacks to facebook's `LoginManager`

Comment: The same way you change any Button background. You can do it with a style, or make your own Drawable to use, etc. But I would start by searching changing Android button styles and pick which way you want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a custom button for facebook login. For that you will need to make your existing facebook button visibility gone and make a custom button with your desired background and on click of your custom buttom call yourFacebookButton().performClick().

Modify your xml with this :

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebook_login_button"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/google_button" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/my_custom_back_ground_button"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/google_button" />
```

On click of your button with id=my_custom_back_ground_button call your facebook button click as `yourFacebookButton.performClick()`

Comment: be aware that this is a hack that may stop working at some point, and not a real solution on how to customize the Facebook SDK